# Let $I$ be an inversion and let $C$ be a circle such that $I(C)$ is also a circle. When do $C$ and $I(C)$ have equal radii?

Tags: geometry, inversive-geometry

Let $I$ be an inversion and let $C$ be a circle such that $I(C)$ is also a circle. When do $C$
and $I(C)$ have equal radii?

When it comes to inversion in a circle, I only know two cases:

1. a circle that does not pass through the origin maps onto a circle
2. a circle punctured at the origin maps onto a line that does not pass through the origin.

However, none of these cases mention anything about the radius. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: It's easier to think in terms of diameters. Let $P$ and $Q$ be the endpoints of the diameter of $C$ that lies on the line joining the center of inversion to the center of $C$. Let $P^\prime=I(P)$ and $Q^\prime = I(Q)$ be their inverses, which determine a diameter of $I(C)$. Under what circumstances do we have $\overline{PQ}\cong\overline{P^\prime Q^\prime}$?